# Big query View schema not matching actual column name in metadata

Tags: google-bigquery

The view; sandbox.test_google_bug on project; stone-outpost-636 has the columns; event_start_date, event_end_date in the query part however in the metadata they are showing as;
event_start_date_usec, event_end_date_usec.

The show stopper is that our api gathers the schema information from the metadata then queries the table based on those columns like; SELECT event_start_date_usec, event_end_date_usec FROM [sandbox.test_google_bug]

As expected, this query fails to execute.

We would appreciate if you can expedite this issue.

The bug has been filed; https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=216

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue still existing for the BigQuery, and also there is a open issue [#35905199](https://issuetracker.google.com/35905199) for public discussion and further updates. But you can try selecting from the view and save the results to a table, then proceed to your next step.

Comment: I am getting this problem in Sep 2020, seems like it is not completely fixed despite the linked issue saying it is Resolved

Comment: More specifically, my issue is slightly different, not about column naming, but a column is missing in the Schema although it gets returned if you query the View.